# Generated column and table names in hibernate with underscore

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

how do I force hibernate to generate db schema such that it converts CamelCase into Underscores (using HBM)? Eg. I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="cz.csas.pdb.be.model.product.passive">

    <class name="foo.BarBaz">

        <id name="barBazId">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
        </id>

        <property name="extractContactType"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I want hibernate  to create table like this (oracle):

```xml
CREATE TABLE "BAR_BAZ"
  (
    "BAR_BAZ_ID"               NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "EXTRACT_CONTACT_TYPE"     VARCHAR2(512 CHAR),
    -- PK etc...
  )
```

I know I can use table/column name in the hbm.xml file, but I want to set it globally (both to save time and prevent errors).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ImprovedNamingStrategy`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) should do exactly what you want. See [3.6. Implementing a NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy).

Comment: It looks like it should work ok, but I get an exception

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Same logical column name referenced by different physical ones: account_charge.PASSIVEACCOUNT => 'passive_account' and 'passiveaccount';

for a simple many-to-one (accountCharge HBM has "<many-to-one name="passiveAccount"/>").

Answer (score 6):

In **JPA 2** (Hibernate 4), [it is even more easier](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/jpa-joined-inheritance-jpa-entity-config.html), just add:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
         value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
```

to your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: Sounds good, but I get a SAX-Parse-Exception which says that the attribute 'value' must be defined. Probably I have some old DTD or Schema for hibernate.cfg.xml. Using hibernate 4.3.5-Final.

Comment: It's working flawlessly, allowed me to use camelCase on entities and snake_case on the database (postgresql), I'm using 4.3.8-Final