# JPA Annotations - How to retrieve a single value from a different table than the current object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, hibernate-annotations

How do you map a single value from a column in another table to the current object?

Example:

```
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="FOO_ID")
    private String fooId;

    @Column(name="FOO_A")
    private String fooA;

    //Column to map to another table?
    //is a one to one mapping - but don't want a separate object for this.
    private String barCode;
}
```

Table: `Fields`

Foo: `FOO_ID, FOO_A`

Bar: `FOO_ID, BAR_CODE`

How do I retrieve the `BAR_CODE` field without creating a separate object (or a secondary table) using `JPA annotations`?

Comment: Note that this is for retrieval only.

Comment: Why dont you want a separate object?

Comment: Its a rather large web service, and I'm trying to reduce object creation and extra data coming back when I only need a single field.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use a [secondary table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTable.html). This allows you to map for an entity, on a one-to-one basis, another table and define column mappings that use it.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@SecondaryTable(name = "other_table", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="FOO_ID"))
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="FOO_ID")
    private String fooId;

    @Column(name="FOO_A")
    private String fooA;

    @Column(table="OtherTable", name="barCode")
    private String barCode;
}
```

Comment: And if there's multiple secondary tables? In my case, the object is a main object with several other tables that are referenced. In some cases, the object creation is necessary, in others, the @ElementCollection works. But I was curious if there was another solution for a single column (like retrieving a description field for a code/description table).

Comment: If you have multiple secondary tables then use ... [`@SecondaryTables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SecondaryTables.html)

Comment: @Perception: shouldn't it be `@Column(table="other_table", name="barCode")` ? Are you exploiting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19454829/1654265) implicitly, is it a typo, or is there some other name conversion elsewhere ?

Comment: What if I have a ManyToOne relationship between Foo and a Bar and still wants to access as a property of class Foo but that value is actually of a Bar, although I have specified Bar with a foreign key association (ManyToOne) in Foo ?