# Java | Persisting String as enum

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a class `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {

  @Id
  private int id;

  @???
  private String cityName;

  // getters and setters

}
```

Now I would like my schema to consist of two tables:

- **MyClassTable**: id INT PRIMARY KEY, city INT FOREIGN KEY ON CityTable.id
- **CityTable**: id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR

Do I have to create a new class for City with two attributes: `int Id` and `String name`? Is it possible to accomplish this using only the `MyClass` class with some special annotation on the `cityName`?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503189/jpa-annotations-how-to-retrieve-a-single-value-from-a-different-table-than-the

Comment: Note that this isn't an enum (either in the Java or the database sense). Yes, you'll need to do exactly what you suggested. (And as a note, it's generally better to use the wrapper class `Integer` or `Long`, as the null value more reliably communicates "entity that hasn't been persisted yet".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create table 'cities' which is a kind of 'dictionary'. So you can map it to [Immutable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-immutability) entity:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {
    @Id private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

(and populate its data on the database layer).

Then your 'data' entity should have a [@ManyToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one) reference to the `City` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_classes")
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    private City city;
}
```

Which will correspond to the following `my_classes` table (PostgreSQL dialect for example) - pay attention on the foreign key `city_id`:

```
create table my_classes (
  id bigint not null constraint my_classes_pkey primary key,
  -- ...
  city_id integer constraint fk_my_classes_cities references cities
)
```

Comment: Thanks, although introduction of all the new mini-classes (Id-value) caused bunch of new problem to pop up.