# How to get a single column value from another entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
-----------           -----------
| Table 1 |           | Table 2 |
|  -----  |           |  -----  |
| ID      |           | ID      |
| NAME    |           | T1_ID   |
| .       |           | .       |
| .       |           | .       |
-----------           -----------

ONE T1.ID ---<- MANY T2.T1_ID
```

I have a table relationship as depicted above. I want to include only the NAME field from Table 1 into the entity that I'd like to create for Table 2 (because Table 1 has way too many fields that I don't want).

`@SecondaryTable` solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503448/2917257) does not work for this scenario because of two reasons:

1. It requires one-to-one relationship between both the tables
2. It requires the foreign key(T1_ID) to serve as the primary key of Table 2 (from what I understand of this exception - org.hibernate.AnnotationException: SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non-primary key)

Kindly suggest if there's a way to avoid pulling in the heavier Table 1 entity into Table 2 entity. Otherwise, the only shortcut I see here is to persist the NAME field in Table 2.

Comment: Can't you just write a query that includes name and the table 2 fields?

Comment: Yes I can, but I wanted to explore if there existed something convenient with hibernate annotations before resorting to writing a query.

Comment: have you tried @ManyToOne annotation on Table 2?